# How to create UISwitch in for loop in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

I have done following code in Viewdid Load for creating  multiple switch programmatically.

```
float x =40.0, y=20.0,height=60.0,width=26.0;

    for (int i =0; i < 3; i++) {

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, height, width);
        UISwitch *switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(flip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [switchControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:switchControl];

        y= y+50.0;
    }

- (IBAction) flip: (id) sender {
    UISwitch *onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    NSLog(@"%@", onoff.on ? @"On" : @"Off");
}
```

After doing this code i am able to create multiple UISwitchs. Now i am not getting how to handle action on every switch. If anyone knows how to handle actions on all switchs please help me. I will appreciate to him/her. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i =0; i < 3; i++) {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, height, width);
    UISwitch *switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    //add tag as index 
    switchControl.tag = i;
    [switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(flip:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [switchControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:switchControl];

    y= y+50.0;
}

- (IBAction) flip: (id) sender {
    UISwitch *onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    NSLog(@"no.%d %@",onoff.tag, onoff.on ? @"On" : @"Off");
    //use onoff.tag , you know which switch you got 
}
```

Comment: its switch, you shud change event to value change not touchup inside

Comment: I have got problem for making them all ON by clicking one button select all.If you know how I can do that please help me.

Answer (score 0):

it is UIControlEventValueChanged event

```
[switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(flip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: r u mad. who did this. leave programming if u don't know how to do this